# <span> value not updated

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dJgLkhUTB-A&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwg2-q6Kvw3Tl_4xhxtIaNlY&index=15) tutorial on making chrome extension. What it is trying to do is

(1) Receive a value from chrome server

(2) Show it

(3) Update it with new input

(4) next time when the expansion is reopened, it shows updated value

The javascript variable `newTotal` is the value to be retrieved and updated. Then it is passed to `<span>` so that the updated value can be shown. I wrote exactly the same code with the video but it didn't show retrieved the value nor updated the value, so I passed the value to `<h2>` instead to check if the target value is being successfully retrieved/stored at all. And it printed the stored value and the updated value. It just looks like `<span>` won't show the value.

html code

`<h2 id="test">TEST</h2>`

`<input type="text" id="amount">`

`<h3>Total Spend : <span id="total">0</span></h3>`

Javascript code

```
$(function(){

    $('#spendAmount').click(function(){
        // bring stored data 'total'
        chrome.storage.sync.get('total', function(budget){

            // If there is an existing 'total' save it to newTotal
            var newTotal = 0;
            if(budget.total){
                newTotal += parseInt(budget.total);
            }

            // If input 'amount' exists, add it to newTotal
            var amount = $('#amount').val();
            if(amount){
                newTotal += parseInt(amount);
            }

            // test : check if newTotal is stored - worked
            $(function(){
                $('#test').text(newTotal);
            })

            // save the updated value to chrome
            chrome.storage.sync.set({'total':newTotal});

            // let 'total' show 'newTotal'
            $('total').text(newTotal);

            // empty input box
            $('#amount').val('');
        });
    });
});
```

I expect it to show stored value (something like 1000), and then when I type 10 and submit, it shows 1010. Mine doesn't show stored value and when I enter 10 and submit, it's still 0 all while I can see that the value was indeed stored in the server because I can print it with .

Comment: If this code runs in the popup, do you know it has a separate devtools where you can **easily** debug your code and make it work in a matter of seconds/minutes? Right-click the popup, click "Inspect", switch to "Sources", set breakpoints in the code, press F5 key to reload the popup and see what happens, inspect the variables, step through the code using the hotkeys or buttons, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

its a mistake in selector

change

```
$('total').text(newTotal);
```

to

```
$('#total').text(newTotal);
```

```js
var newTotal = 0;
            if(1000){
                newTotal += parseInt(1000);
            }

            // If input 'amount' exists, add it to newTotal
            var amount = 10;
            if(amount){
                newTotal += parseInt(amount);
            }

            // test : check if newTotal is stored - worked
            //$(function(){
                $('#test').text(newTotal);
            //})


            // let 'total' show 'newTotal'
            $('#total').text(newTotal);

            // empty input box
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="test"></span>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you find any other mistake though? It still isn't working and I'm really lost.

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers you should check your code, it is very simple solution. console.log the totals and  check you are using the exact selectors.

Answer (score 0):

you have made a mistake :

```
1. You have missed # in the selector :
```

`$('total').text(newTotal);`

```
2. Try to use innerHTML rather than text as that might cause problem but not in what you are trying to achieve here.
```